# Count no of rows after autofilering in excel using powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, autofilter

I am new to power shell script I am unable to get no of rows after auto filtering in excel.

Googling doesn't help much. Someone kindly help on this

```
$xl = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$xl.Visible = $True
$xl.DisplayAlerts = $False
$wb = $xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Dinesh\Downloads\jtrac-export2")
$ws = $wb.Worksheets.Item(1)
$ws.activate()
$xl.Range("A1:G100").Select()
$rn = $xl.Range("A1:G100").Select()
sleep 7
$A = "Service Request"
$L = "Incident"
$G = "2 - High"
$H = "3 - Medium"
$COUNTA = 3
#$xlFilterValues = 7
$xl.selection.AutoFilter(6,$L)
$counter = $ws.UsedRange.SpecialCells(12).Rows.Count
Write-Host $counter
sleep 10
$xl.selection.AutoFilter(6,$A)
$counter = $ws.UsedRange.SpecialCells(12).Rows.Count
Write-Host $counter

______________________________________________________________________
```

Result for this is 8 but in the excel no of rows after filtering is 21   and total rows is 28(without Filtering)

```
$xl.selection.AutoFilter(6,$L)

$counter = $ws.UsedRange.SpecialCells(12).Rows.Count
Write-Host $counter
```

Result for this is 1 but in the excel no of rows after filtering is 7 and total rows is 28(without Filtering)

```
$xl.selection.AutoFilter(6,$A)
$counter = $ws.UsedRange.SpecialCells(12).Rows.Count
Write-Host $counter
```

Comment: If the filtered data block is solid (no blank cells), you can use the native worksheet SUBTOTAL or AGGREGATE to count visible cells in a column. If there may be blank cells then you need to iterate through the Areas of SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).

Comment: I tried SUBTOTAL with counta and xlcelltypevisible throwing some error.. I am not sure how to use.. Can you guide me how to use it.

Comment: [edit] Just had another look; if you are filtering for `"Incident"` then there should be no blank cells and subtotal(103, column(L)) should be the correct count. Maybe `$counter = $xl.subtotal(103, $ws.columns("L"))`. Of copurse, that is going to count the column header label as well.

Comment: I think I tried this but throwing some range error. I'll again check and let you know.

Comment: Maybe` $counter = $xl.subtotal(103, $ws.columns(12))` would be better.

Comment: Method invocation failed because [System.__ComObject] doesn't contain a method named 'column'.
At C:\Users\Dinesh\Secondscript.ps1:17 char:39
+ $counter = $xl.subtotal(103,$ws.column <<<< (6))
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (column:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound                                                                              Getting error

Comment: Should be $ws.columnS(12)

Comment: Sorry i already tried with s           Method invocation failed because [System.__ComObject] doesn't contain a method named 'columns'.

Comment: Ok, then `$xl.Range("L2:L100")` or `$xl.Columns(12)`. The range seems to work in a previous command line. Honestly don't know why it has to be $xl and not $ws though.

Comment: Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass] doesn't contain a method named 'subt
otal'.                                                                                                                     Getting error after  "$counter = $xl.subtotal(103,$xl.Range("L2:L100"))"               its okay i'll try someother way